# where is this function with exponential differentiable?

Tags: derivatives

I need to find out where the function

$$f(x,y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
    e^{\tfrac{1}{x^2+y^2-1}}, & x^2+y^2<1  \\
    0,  & x^2+y^2\geq1
\end{array}
\right.$$
is differentiable. Here is my progress

For $x^2+y^2<1$, I can use the chain rule
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{-2xe^{\tfrac{1}{x^2+y^2-1}}}{(x^2+y^2-1)^2}, \ \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{-2ye^{\tfrac{1}{x^2+y^2-1}}}{(x^2+y^2-1)^2}.$$

This partial derivatives are continiuos, so $f$ is differentiable.

For $x^2+y^2>1$, $f$ is constant, then its partial derivatives are zero and $f$ is differenciable in this case too.

Finally, for $x^2+y^2=1$, the fraction $\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2-1}$ goes to $0$ and $f(x,y)=1$ and we have
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0.$$

Therefore, $f$ is differentiable in the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Is it correct?

Comment: If $x^2+y^2>1$ why would $f$ be constant? Also if $x^2+y^2=1$ then $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2-1}$ is not $0$ but undefined.

Comment: In your last case, the demoninator equals zero, so the fraction is undefined ("infinity"). Is it possible you are missing a minus sign in argument of the exponential ?

Comment: @AndréArmatowski the 2nd sentence (I reformat the function for it), it says that $f$ is zero for $x^2+y^2\geq1$. So, in particular, for $x^2+y^2>1$, we have $f(x,y)=0$, which is constant, right?.

Comment: @M1183 here it is the question from the book https://photos.app.goo.gl/UB2FFvrassESpjiu6

Comment: @AndréArmatowski why 0/0?

Comment: Consider when $x^2+y^2$ approaches $1$ but $1-x^2-y^2 > 0$ , then $(x^2+y^2-1)^2 \to 0$ and $e^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2-1}} \to e^{-\infty} "=" 0$

Comment: @AndréArmatowski but there is no square for $x^2+y^2-1$

Comment: In order for the partial derivative to be continuous you need $$\lim_{x^2+y^2 \to 1} \frac{-2xe^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2-1}}}{(x^2+y^2-1)^2}$$  to be zero.

Comment: @AndréArmatowski understood now but is this case $x^2+y^2<1$ implies that $(x^2+y^2-1) ^2$ is never zero, so the partial derivatives are never igual to $0/0$

Comment: True, but the limit approaches $0/0$ which is what we are concerned with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109848/discussion-between-andre-armatowski-and-marcos-paulo).

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider $$f(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
    e^{\dfrac{1}{t-1}}, & t<1  \\
    0,  & t\geq1
\end{array}
\right.$$
Which is differentiable and its composition with differentiable $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2$

For partial derivative let's consider any $(x,y)$ for which $x^2+y^2=1$. Then
$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0-}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{(x+ \Delta x)^2+y^2-1}}}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0-}\frac{1}{\Delta x}e^{\frac{1}{(x +\Delta x)^2- x^2}}=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0-}\frac{1}{\Delta x} e^{\frac{1}{2 x \Delta x+\Delta x^2}}=0$$

Comment: Should I use lateral limits?

Comment: I tried to develop yor last sentence, but I gave just got this $$\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow0-}\frac{e}{\Delta x\,e^{(x+\Delta x)^2+y^2}}=e^{1-x^2+y^2}\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow0-}\frac{1}{\Delta x\,e^{2x\Delta x}}$$

Comment: Added more steps on last limit in answer, used $y^2-1=-x^2$.

Comment: L'Hospital rule now?

Comment: As you like, I prefer estimation, equivalence, taylor etc. So, almost all your main statements was correct.

Comment: All partial derivatives?

Comment: Sorry, what you mean under "all"? Function is symmetric against variables.

Comment: I meant the partial derivatives that I computed. By the way, I do not know what you mean by "function is symmetric against variables"

Comment: $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$, so it's enough to investigate with respect to one variable.

Comment: Understood now. Thanks again